# Support branding image on Android =< 11 (Splash Screen)

Tags: android, react-native, android-splashscreen

I'm testing Splash screen on different devices with diferent Android versions (=< 11) and all works fine, but branding image not appear.

According to docs branding image is only supported on Android 12+.

Is there any workaround to this? I really need to support for older versions.

```
<style name="BootTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/bootsplash_background</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@mipmap/bootsplash_logo</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBrandingImage">@drawable/brand_logo</item> <!-- Don't work -->
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
</style>
```

Working with [react-native-bootsplash](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash) (react-native)

Comment: you have always been able to show a slash screen just not the way android 12 supports it. Just create an activity that shows the brand and launch through that